# Control events not firing on WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a WPF project that I started from another (non-WPF) project in my solution. The window has several buttons that I want to forward to the initiating project but it looks like no events are fired on my window.

I'm able to set properties in my window, which update my UI correctly so at least one direction is working.

I instantiate my window like this:

```
PanelThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    panel = new Panel.MainWindow(true);
    panel.onCommandSent += Panel_onCommandSent;
    panel.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
});
PanelThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
PanelThread.IsBackground = true;
PanelThread.Start();
```

How can I get my WPF window to fire events?

---

EDIT:

It seems that the `Click` events are firing... just not the `MouseDown` events.
The event handlers are generated from the designer so I see no reason why this event would behave any different from the `Click` event.

Comment: How is Panel.MainWindow defined? Please post the code and the XAML markup.

Comment: Use PreviewMouseDown event instead of MouseDown .